# Can I find traditional roleplaying in Fastaval?

Tags: convention

[Fastaval](http://www.fastaval.dk/) is famous for one-shot scenarios, many of which are freeform/[jeepform](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107600/what-is-jeepform-vi-%c3%a5ker-jeep)/structured freeform in style. That is, at least, true of the scenarios that have been translated to English or Finnish that I have read.

Freeform scenarios are not really what I look for in gaming. Hence the question:

Are there other kinds of gaming going on in Fastaval, also?

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact the organizers. You can find mail addresses on the homepage: https://www.fastaval.dk/om-fastaval/kontakt/