# What is jeepform / vi åker jeep?

Tags: terminology, larp, freeform

Some games are occasionally termed jeepform. I have also encountered the Swedish phrase "Vi åker jeep" (We travel with/by jeep), which seems to refer to the same thing. There is even [a website](http://jeepen.org/), which is not really helpful at providing a description or definition.

What is jeepform about and what sorts of games do they play or make?

Answer (score 5):

Jeepform is the name of a group of Swedish roleplayers and game designers and, by extensions, the brand of the games authored by members of the group.

Because of the gaming culture inside the group, Jeepform games are often similar in theme and often share some techniques and ideas.

Their games often border experimental/improvisational theatre, as can be seen by several entries in their [Dictionary](http://jeepen.org/dict/).

The Freeform and Jeepform entries of the dictionary, when combined together, help understand what Jeepform really is to them. It is their own brand of freeform games, that are games where the emerging story takes precedence over the form.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the shared theme, or what it means for emerging story to take precedence over the form?

Comment: @Thanuir unfortunately, my knowledge of the subject is second hand at best. I knew of the group and of what they were (and even played one or two of their games, and heard talking about some others) before your question, but that story over form is taken almost verbatim from their site. I suspect that it is in counterposition to "let's use a system and then pretend that the events it creates form a story" - basically a way to state that creating a story is what matters in their games and not a byproducyt - but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: Could you quote those two entries so that readers don't have to read the whole dictionary and guess which two combine to explain it?